# detect height with jquery and dynamic content

Tags: jquery, css, cakephp

i have a div that has to be vertical aligned, the text inside the div is dynamicly generated, so i need to get the div size with the generated content and then set it to other div so it can be vertical aligned.

This is my markup

```
<?php foreach ($necesidades as $necesidad): ?>
    <div class="guia-wrap">
         <div class="tit">
              <div><?php echo $necesidad->getTituloByPais($pais) ?></div>
         </div>
         <div class="desa">
              <div><?php echo html_entity_decode($necesidad->getDescripcion()) ?></div>
         </div>

         <script>
             $(document).ready(function(){
                 altura = $('.desa').height();
                 $(".tit").css("height", altura);
                 $(".tab_content").hide();
             });
         </script> 
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

so, i am getting .desa's height and setting it to .tit. But as several .guia-wraps are generated, i don't know how to geat each .desa's heights and setting them to their own .tit

this is the css

```
.tit { 
    display: table; 
    float: left; 
    width: 213px; 
    border-right:1px solid #dedede; 
    height: 100%; 
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 14px; 
    color: #666666; 
    background: #f6f6f6;
 }
.tit div {
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
    padding: 15px;
}
.desa { 
    display: table;
    float: right; 
    width: 476px; 
    font-family: arial; 
    font-size: 12px; 
    height: 100%; 
    color: #959595; 
}
.desa div {
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
    padding: 15px;
}
```

Hope its clear enough. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Jquery you can do some using [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.guia-wrap').each(function(){
      var h = $('.desa',this).css('height');
      $('.tit', this).css('height',h)
   })
})
```

Comment: worked flawlessly. I forgot about the each function lol. Thank you very much!